# Passing param to controller from view fails, when data structure is large

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
Rails 5.2
```

In my config/routes.rb, I have:

```
post 'books_author', to: 'books#author'
```

When I run rake routes, I get:

```
books_author POST /books_author(.:format) books#author
```

In my app/controllers/books_controller.rb, I have:

```
def author
  books_collection = params[:books_collection]
  author_notes = params[:author_notes]
  render json: author_notes["2019"][author_notes]['main_author']
end
```

And in my view, I have the following:

```
td
  = link_to 'Author Details', books_author_path(books_collection: books_collection, author_notes: author_notes), method: :post
```

The author_notes data structure is pretty large.

When I run the app, and click on the link, I get the following error message:

```
This site can’t be reached
The connection was reset
```

I see this in the browser, but there are no entries in the development.log file.

If I double click on the top browser bar, to select it, and copy and paste it into a text editor, I see that the entire request is there (pretty large one).

I tried passing a smaller data structure, and that worked fine. Any ideas how to pass a larger data structure from a view, to a controller method?

## Solution

```
td
  = form_tag books_author_path do
    = hidden_field_tag 'books_collection', books_collection
    = hidden_field_tag 'author_notes', author_notes
    = submit_tag 'Author Details'
```

Comment: The view above belongs to which action?

Comment: @RajdeepSingh see my question. It belongs to the author action

Comment: And you are posting to the same action through `link_to`? According to your routes `post 'books_author', to: 'books#author'`, `books_author` is pointing to the same action `author`

Comment: Yes, this is what books_author_path is

Comment: You should use a form instead of `link_to` to pass large amount of data, check my edited answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make a few changes, in `author` action, use instance variables, so that they could be accessed in the view

```
def author
  books_collection = params[:books_collection]
  author_notes = params[:author_notes]
  render json: @author_notes["2019"][author_notes]['main_author']
end
```

In view

```
td
  = form_tag books_author_path do
    = hidden_field_tag 'books_collection', books_collection
    = hidden_field_tag 'author_notes', author_notes
    = f.submit 'Author Details'
```

Try it once!

---------from comments-----------

To render `author.html.slim` you need to define html format, currently the `author` action is just rendering `json`, do this

```
def author
  books_collection = params[:books_collection]
  author_notes = params[:author_notes]
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.json { author_notes["2019"][author_notes]['main_author'] }
  end  
end
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: That does not address my question. I am passing these variables TO the controller FROM the view, through the link_to, not the other way around. The controller is NOT rendering the view the link_to is in

Comment: This is a table (what the td is for), not a form

Comment: @EastsideDeveloper can you tell me the file name of your view where `link
to` is in?

Comment: You can't pass a huge chunk of data as query params, that's the thing, you need a form for it!

Comment: The link_to is in the books_list.html.slim view, and the controller action (author), renders the author.html.slilm

Comment: What needs to happen is = form_tag books_author_path do, instead of = form_tag books_author_path do |f|

Comment: @EastsideDeveloper Yeah right, my bad, `form_tag` doesn't have a form object, so did it solve your problem?